# How to create a new variable that outputs that rows' final response

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a new variable in an existing dataframe that corresponds to the last value of that row's responses and also identifies which column that response came from but I'm having no luck being able to figure this out. Thanks very much in advance!

I'm hoping to go from:

```
  id X_1 X_2 X_3 X_4 X_5
1  1   1   3   5  NA  NA
2  2   2   4  NA  NA  NA
3  3   5   5   6   5   3
4  4   6   6  NA  NA  NA
5  5   8   2   6   6   6
6  6  12   3   2   2  NA
```

To this:

```
  id X_1 X_2 X_3 X_4 X_5 X_final X_final_location
1  1   1   3   5  NA  NA       5              X_3
2  2   2   4  NA  NA  NA       4              X_2
3  3   5   5   6   5   3       3              X_5
4  4   6   6  NA  NA  NA       6              X_2
5  5   8   2   6   6   6       6              X_5
6  6  12   3   2   2  NA       2              X_4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use `tail` to get the last element and `x[!is.na(x)]` to only look in non empty values. `apply` is to apply the function in each row of the data.frame:

```
x_final <- apply(data, 1, \(x) tail(x[!is.na(x)],1))
x_final_location <- names(data)[apply(data, 1, \(x) max(which(!is.na(x))))]
 
cbind(data,x_final,x_final_location)
```

Returns:

```
  id X_1 X_2 X_3 X_4 X_5 x_final x_final_location
1  1   1   3   5  NA  NA       5              X_3
2  2   2   4  NA  NA  NA       4              X_2
3  3   5   5   6   5   3       3              X_5
4  4   6   6  NA  NA  NA       6              X_2
5  5   8   2   6   6   6       6              X_5
6  6  12   3   2   2  NA       2              X_4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find the index of the last occured (not null) values by row with,

```
 index <- rowSums(!is.na(df[,2:6]))
```

Then you can get the values wrt those indexes and make the assignment,

```
 df$X_final<-df[ as.matrix(data.frame(df[,1], index+1))]
 df$X_final_location <- paste0("X_",index)
```

gives,

```
#  id X_1 X_2 X_3 X_4 X_5 X_final X_final_location
#  1  1   1   3   5  NA  NA       5              X_3
#  2  2   2   4  NA  NA  NA       4              X_2
#  3  3   5   5   6   5   3       3              X_5
#  4  4   6   6  NA  NA  NA       6              X_2
#  5  5   8   2   6   6   6       6              X_5
#  6  6  12   3   2   2  NA       2              X_4
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is tidyverse approach:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-id, names_to = "X_final_location", values_to = "X_final") %>%
  group_by(id) %>% 
  na.omit() %>% 
  slice(n()) %>% 
  full_join(df, by="id")
```

```
     id X_final_location X_final   X_1   X_2   X_3   X_4   X_5
  <int> <chr>              <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     1 X_3                    5     1     3     5    NA    NA
2     2 X_2                    4     2     4    NA    NA    NA
3     3 X_5                    3     5     5     6     5     3
4     4 X_2                    6     6     6    NA    NA    NA
5     5 X_5                    6     8     2     6     6     6
6     6 X_4                    2    12     3     2     2    NA
```

Answer (score 0):

### Code

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(
    X_final = tail(na.omit(c_across()),1),
    X_final_location = names(data)[length(na.omit(c_across()))-1]
    )
```

### Output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 8
# Rowwise: 
     id   X_1   X_2   X_3   X_4   X_5 X_final X_final_location
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>   <int> <chr>           
1     1     1     3     5    NA    NA       5 X_3             
2     2     2     4    NA    NA    NA       4 X_2             
3     3     5     5     6     5     3       3 X_5             
4     4     6     6    NA    NA    NA       6 X_2             
5     5     8     2     6     6     6       6 X_5             
6     6    12     3     2     2    NA       2 X_4
```